# How to solve absolute path error while installing a software into another computer made in python?

Tags: python, tkinter, windows-installer, cx-freeze

I had made an app using python tkinter and created an msi file using cx_Freeze but when I am trying to install it in other machine it is showing me **traceback error** of **cx_Freeze: Python error in main script**[image]

Actually the software is taking my own computer's path for its startup file but I want the relative path in the machine of the actual user. So, how can I solve this? Do I have to do something while creating the msi built or anything else. Please help me!

Here is my code of setup:-

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import sys
import os 
base = None

if sys.platform == 'win32':
    base = "Win32GUI"
elif sys.platform == 'win64':
    base = "Win64GUI"

PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR=os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR,'tcl','tcl8.6')
os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR,'tcl','tk8.6')


include_files=[(os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs','tk86t.dll'),os.path.join('lib','tk86.dll')),
                (os.path.join(PYTHON_INSTALL_DIR, 'DLLs','tcl86t.dll'),os.path.join('lib','tcl86.dll')),
                ]

executables = [Executable("text_editor.py", base=base, icon=".\icon.ico", shortcutName='SOHAM TEXT EDITOR', shortcutDir='DesktopFolder')]


setup(
    name = "SOHAM TEXT EDITOR INSTALLER",
    options = {"build_exe": {"packages":["tkinter","os"], "include_files":include_files}},
    # options = {'build_exe':{'include_files'}},
    version = "0.01",
    description = "Hi I am Soham, I had made this Text Editor using Tkinter Application in Python, I had made this project for edit text, this is very compatable to user and easy to understand.",
    author = "SOHAM DAS BISWAS",
    executables = executables
    )
```

Comment: Use relative path and include the files with the exe and `pyinstaller` is much better i guess

Comment: Sir, I want to make it as msi application, but pyinstaller make the file as exe which is directly run the program. I want user install the program and then the program will run.

Comment: Okay then use `pyinstaller` make an exe and then use `inno setup` to make an installer out of it